# Create shortcut to iOS app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a simple watchOS app that basically has a button to do the exact same thing as another button on the main iOS app.

If so, how do I do this? Do you recommend any guide or blog post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly doable. I'd recommend [this watchOS 2 tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watchos-2-communicating-with-a-counterpart--cms-24372). You're going to use the [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html) framework to communicate with the parent app. The specific method you'll use to send data to the parent app is `sendMessage(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, is it possible to share a value of a label to the watch?

Comment: Yes, of course. You'd use the same method in the other direction.